# How to push changes to repository after deleting and creating a new one

Tags: git, github

I was facing issues with my github repository and has decided to delete and create a new one with the same name.

I then typed this command in order to push the changes again to the repository:

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:Sidney-Dev/owlproperty.git
```

But it gave me a fatal error:

fatal: remote origin already exists.

I also tried

```
git push origin --force
```

but it takes forever to run and it does not work.

Is there a better fix for this?

Comment: If it already exist on remote, why not just clone it from there ?

Comment: you need to delete your remote too

Comment: @Dhirendra, the github repository is currently empty, and what I want is to push the code that I have locally into that repo

Comment: Does `git push origin --force` literally take "forever" (i.e. never terminates unless interrupted) or does it "not work" in some other way?

Comment: Please try `git push -uv origin master` to push & update your question with generated logs.

Comment: Also, update origin before push with `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:Sidney-Dev/owlproperty.git`

Answer (score 2):

You first have to update your local repository's (now invalid) knowledge about the (now replaced) remote repository:

```
git fetch origin --prune
```

Then you should be able to simply

```
git push origin
```

to push the current branch or

```
git push --all origin
```

to push all local branches.